# Parse Key and Value Field using Python Json file

Tags: python, json

Im given a JSON file like so:

```
[{
           "ANIMAL_NAME FOOD HOUSENAME": "Jack Cat Chewy Food Owners House"
   
   },
{
           "ANIMAL_NAME FOOD HOUSENAME": "Harry Parrot Bird Chewy Food Good A Owners House"
   
   },
   {
           "ANIMAL_NAME FOOD HOUSENAME": "Fred Dog Dog Fun Steak Rack Dog"
     },
  {
           "ANIMAL_NAME FOOD HOUSENAME": "Fred Dog Dog Some Kind of Food Some Kind of House"
     }]
```

I would like the json to look like so

```
    [{
           "ANIMAL_NAME": "Jack Cat" 
            "FOOD": "Chewy Food"
            "HOUSENAME": "Owners House"
   
   },

    {       "ANIMAL_NAME": "Harry Parrot Bird" 
            "FOOD": "Chewy Food Good"
            "HOUSENAME": "A Owners House"
   
   },
   {
            "ANIMAL_NAME": "Fred Dog Dog" 
            "FOOD": "Fun Steak Rack"
            "HOUSENAME": "Dog"
     },
  {
            "ANIMAL_NAME": "Fred Dog Dog" 
            "FOOD": "Some Kind of Food"
            "HOUSENAME": "Some Kind of Food Some Kind of House"
     }]
```

I am not sure how to go about this as the data is unpredictable. I would like to parse these the keys and the values. Here is my code so far

```
with open('data.json') as file:
data= json.load(file)
for i, fact in enumerate(data['ANIMAL_NAME FOOD HOUSENAME'], 1):
```

Comment: Why doesn't the json file have some kind of delimiter to separate the three things? You can't just go about guessing how many words fall under which category and build logic with that.

Comment: You should work with whoever provide the file to fix its structure at the time of creation.

Comment: it is puzzle...?

Comment: Hi there unfortunately this is how the document was given to me. Should I maybe hard code all the ANIMAL_NAME  to make parsing possible like using find and replace ie Jack cat will just be Jack cat\n and that could be denoted as a separate line and hard code food? How would I do this in one call ?